How to assign a DB instance as the writer in an Aurora DB cluster in CloudFormation?
This example show how to create an Aurora DB cluster with two DB instances using CloudFormation. In the example, there are two DB instances, RDSDBInstance1 and RDSDBInstance2. How do I explicitly control which instance becomes the writer and which instance becomes the reader. For instance, I might assign RDSDBInstance2 to be of a more powerful instance class, so I would want this DB instance to be the writer.

It doesn't say in the docs, but I believe that the first instance created is the writer.  You could also try to add priority tier to your instances, that might make a CloudFormation to change what instance is the writer (lower value is higher priority, it can go up to 15)

Thank you @Caldazar. It seems like the first instance defined in the CloudFormation template is always the writer instance. Thank you also for the tip about the PromotionTier.

hi @Caldazar, i was able to experience a case where the first DB instance defined in the template was not made to be the writer...

You can use the DependsOn attribute to control which DB instance is created first. Most probably, the first DB instance created is assigned as the writer.
